# Appfog loadbalancing with node.js

Tags: node.js, http, appfog

Will Appfog load balancer forward multiple outstanding requests to the same node.js instance or does it allow only one outstanding request per instance? I couldn't find information on this on Appfog website.

Since one of the advantages of node.js is that a node.js instance can concurrently process multiple requests (with I/O associated with requests being asynchronously processed), if a load balancer only allows one outstanding request per node.js instance, I believe that we are not fully utilizing the power of node.js - am I right?

Comment: "I've read that Heroku allows only one outstanding request per instance" source?

Comment: I remember to have read something of that nature - but can't recall where (if I get it I will add a comment). However, from Heroku's documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dynos-and-requests): "Multi-threaded or event-driven environments like Java, Unicorn, EventMachine, and Node.js can handle many concurrent requests.". I've updated my post - @Prinzhorn: thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Quoting from: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing-bamboo: "For Bamboo apps, router nodes limit the number of active requests per dyno to 1 and queue additional requests." However, this seems to be only applicable to their Bamboo stack. For their cedar stack (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#simultaneous-connections): "The herokuapp.com routing stack allows many concurrent connections to web dynos.". Here's where I first came across this issue: http://news.rapgenius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-lyrics.

Answer (score 0):

Since long polling is working well, definitely it is more than on outstanding req per instance. Only question is how many outstanding requests do the load balancer allow.